# How to align equations tags when using empheq?

Tags: math-mode, tags, empheq

I am trying to align the equations tagging with the equation itself, but it seems this does not work

[image]

Also, is it possible to set all math to bold for all math environment?

My MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\adjustboxMath}[1]{\adjustbox{cframe=black 0.141mm 1.06mm 0mm}{$#1$}}

\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand{\basmahspace}{\mspace{0.61\thinmuskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        
        \item The state-space representation of a system dynamics is given as
            
            \begin{empheq}[box=\adjustboxMath]{alignat=2}
                \dot{\mathbf{x}} &= \mathbf{A} \basmahspace \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{B} \basmahspace \mathbf{u}
                \medspace \empheqrbrace \text{State equations} {\vrule width0mm height6.9mm}
            \\
                \dot{\mathbf{y}} &= \mathbf{C} \basmahspace \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{D} \basmahspace \mathbf{u}
                \medspace \empheqrbrace \text{Output equation}
            \end{empheq}
            
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the problem is the `\vrule`. You don't need it.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\adjustboxMath}[1]{\adjustbox{cframe=black 0.141mm 1.06mm 0mm}{$#1$}}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{empheq}[box=\adjustboxMath]{align}
  \dot{\mathbf{x}} &=
  \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{B}\mathbf{u}\;\Bigg\rbrace \text{State equations}
  \\
  \dot{\mathbf{y}} &=
  \mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{D}\mathbf{u}\;\Bigg\rbrace \text{Output equation}
\end{empheq}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]